# left menu not scrolling when add submenu in drawer.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using drawer.min.js for left menubar. It is working fine without adding submenus to the main menu. When I am adding submenus I am unable to scroll down. when I clicked outside of the menu then it is working fine. I am unable to find what is the problem. I have done almost 80% of the project and I  don't want to change the plugin. This problem continues all major browsers.

here is my code

```css
.drawer-open {
 overflow: hidden!important
}
.drawer-nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 36.25rem;
 height: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.drawer-brand {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 3.75rem;
 display: block;
 padding-right: .75rem;
 padding-left: .75rem;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff
}
.drawer-menu {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px 30px;
}



.drawer-menu-item {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'AvenirLTStdBook';
 font-size: 19px;
}
.drawer-menu-item:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: transparent
}
.drawer-overlay {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2)*/
}
.drawer-open .drawer-overlay {
 display: block
}
.drawer--top .drawer-nav {
 top: -100%;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: top .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 transition: top .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1)
}
.drawer--top.drawer-open .drawer-nav {
 top: 0
}
.drawer--top .drawer-hamburger, .drawer--top.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger {
 right: 0
}
.drawer--left .drawer-nav {
 left: -36.25rem;
 -webkit-transition: left .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 transition: left .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1)
}
.drawer--left, .drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-nav, .drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-navbar .drawer-hamburger {
 left: 0px;
}

.drawer-hamburger {
 left: 160px;
}

.drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger {
 left: 36.25rem
}
.drawer--right .drawer-nav {
 right: -36.25rem;
 -webkit-transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1)
}
.drawer--right .drawer-hamburger, .drawer--right.drawer-open .drawer-nav, .drawer--right.drawer-open .drawer-navbar .drawer-hamburger {
 right: 0
}
.drawer--right.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger {
 right: 36.25rem
}
.drawer-hamburger {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 4;
 top: 0;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 width: 3rem;
 padding: 0;
 padding: 18px .75rem 30px;
 -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 background-color: transparent
}
.drawer-hamburger:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: transparent
}
.drawer-hamburger-icon {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px
}
.drawer-hamburger-icon, .drawer-hamburger-icon:after, .drawer-hamburger-icon:before {
 width: 100%;
 height: 3px;
 -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.drawer-hamburger-icon:after, .drawer-hamburger-icon:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: -10px;
 left: 0;
 content: " "
}
.drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
 top: 10px
}
.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon {
 background-color: transparent
}
.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:after, .drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:before {
 top: 0
}
.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg)
}
.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
.sr-only {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 margin: -1px;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0
}
.sr-only-focusable:active, .sr-only-focusable:focus {
 position: static;
 overflow: visible;
 clip: auto;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0
}
.drawer--sidebar, .drawer--sidebar .drawer-contents {
 background-color: #fff
}

@media (min-width:64em) {
.drawer--sidebar .drawer-hamburger {
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden
}
.drawer--sidebar .drawer-nav {
 display: block;
 -webkit-transform: none;
 transform: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: 12.5rem;
 height: 100%
}
.drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-nav {
 left: 0;
 border-right: 1px solid #ddd
}
.drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-contents {
 margin-left: 12.5rem
}
.drawer--sidebar.drawer--right .drawer-nav {
 right: 0;
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd
}
.drawer--sidebar.drawer--right .drawer-contents {
 margin-right: 12.5rem
}
.drawer--sidebar .drawer-container {
 max-width: 48rem
}
}

@media (min-width:75em) {
.drawer--sidebar .drawer-nav {
 width: 36.25rem
}
.drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-contents {
 margin-left: 36.25rem
}
.drawer--sidebar.drawer--right .drawer-contents {
 margin-right: 36.25rem
}
.drawer--sidebar .drawer-container {
 max-width: 60rem
}
}
.drawer--navbarTopGutter {
 padding-top: 3.75rem
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-navbar-header {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 background-color: #fff
}
.drawer-navbar {
 z-index: 3;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%
}
.drawer-navbar--fixed {
 position: fixed
}
.drawer-navbar-header {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 height: 3.75rem;
 padding: 0 .75rem;
 text-align: center
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-brand {
 line-height: 3.75rem;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 text-decoration: none
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-brand:hover {
 background-color: transparent
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-nav {
 padding-top: 3.75rem
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-menu {
 padding-bottom: 7.5rem
}

@media (min-width:64em) {
.drawer-navbar {
 height: 3.75rem;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 background-color: #fff
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-navbar-header {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-menu--right {
 float: right
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-menu li {
 float: left
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-menu-item {
 line-height: 3.75rem;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-hamburger {
 display: none
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-nav {
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 overflow: visible;
 width: auto;
 height: 3.75rem;
 padding-top: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0)
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-menu {
 padding: 0
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 width: 36.25rem;
 border: 1px solid #ddd
}
.drawer-navbar .drawer-dropdown-menu-item {
 padding-left: .75rem
}
}
.drawer-dropdown-menu {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.drawer-dropdown-menu>li {
 width: 100%;
 list-style: none
}
.drawer-dropdown-menu-item {
 line-height: 3.75rem;
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 padding-right: .75rem;
 padding-left: 1.5rem;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #222
}
.drawer-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #555;
 background-color: transparent
}
.drawer-dropdown.open>.drawer-dropdown-menu {
 display: block
}


.drawer-dropdown span {
 position:relative;
}

.drawer-dropdown span:before {
    content: "+";
    font-family: 'AvenirLTStdBook';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0px;
}

.drawer-dropdown.open span:before {
 content: "-";
    font-family: 'AvenirLTStdBook';
}

.drawer-container {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto
}

@media (min-width:64em) {
.drawer-container {
 max-width: 60rem
}
}

@media (min-width:75em) {
.drawer-container {
 max-width: 70rem
}
}





.drawer-menu li a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'AvenirLTStdBook';
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-weight: normal;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.drawer-menu li a img {
 padding-right:15px;
}

.drawer-brand {
 color: #fff !important;
 font-family: 'AvenirLTStdMedium';
 font-size: 22px !important;
 line-height: 50px !important;
}

.drawer-brand img {
 padding-right:8px;
}


.drawer-dropdown-menu li {
 margin-left:50px;
 position:relative;
 padding-left:10px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-menu li:before {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 width:4px;
 height:4px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#02a6e7;
 top:10px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-menu li a {
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:26px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 transition:all 0.4s;
}


.drawer-dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 color:#ccc !important;
 transition:all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link href="css/drawer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body class="drawer drawer--left">

<div role="banner">
   
    <nav class="drawer-nav" role="navigation">
      <ul class="drawer-menu">
        <li><a class="drawer-brand drawer-toggle" href="javascript:void();"><img src="images/menu/close-icon.png"> HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAVORITES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
        
        <li class="drawer-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void();" class="submenu"> SETUP <span>&nbsp;</span></a>
        
       <ul class="drawer-dropdown-menu dropdown">
            <li><a href="setup.php">SETUP</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-company.php">SETUP COMPANY</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-client-preferences.php">SETUP CLIENT PREFERENCES</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-appointments-emails.php">SETUP APPOINTMENTS & EMAILS</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-services.php">SETUP SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-inventory.php">SETUP INVENTORY</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SETUP FAVORITES</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-memberships.php">SETUP MEMBERSHIPS</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-workers.php">SETUP WORKERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-ticket-preferences.php">SETUP TICKET PREFERENCES</a></li>
          </ul>
        
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#"> CLIENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> appointments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> MEMBER CHECK IN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GIFT BALANCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">inventory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">check out</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">reports</a></li>
        
        <li class="drawer-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void();" class="submenu">marketing <span>&nbsp;</span></a>
        
        <ul class="drawer-dropdown-menu dropdown">
            <li><a href="setup-promotions.php">Setup Promotions</a></li>
            <li><a href="setup-rewards.php">Setup Rewards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marketing Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="marketing-sets.php">Marketing Sets</a></li>
            <li><a href="marketing-reports.php">Marketing Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Email Activity</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        
        </li>
        
        
        
        <li><a href="#">time clock</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">logout</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>



 <div id="wrapper">
 <header>
  <div class="top-header">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-link drawer-toggle">
       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> HOME
                        </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
 </header>
 
 
 

 

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iScroll/5.2.0/iscroll.js"></script>
 <script src="js/drawer.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.drawer').drawer();
    });
  </script>
  
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submenu").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").slideToggle();
    }); 
});
  </script>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in console, it is working when we right click the mouse and click on inspect element

Comment: Please break this down and add to a JS Fiddle, anyone wanting to fix this would have to do the same.

Comment: Here is the JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/y0o09ah2/1/

Comment: I have menus from Home to Logout on left side panel, when we click on setup dropdown, i am unable to scroll down till last li item Logout. same problem when i click on marketing menu, it is showing dropdown but i am unable to scroll down